# use model's value to create a Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a model which is as follows:

```
class BloodTestType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.type)

class BloodParameters(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(BloodTestType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    minimum_value = models.FloatField()
    maximum_value = models.FloatField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    required = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES =  [
    ('B', 'Both'),
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 100,choices = GENDER_CHOICES,default = 'B')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.type) + ' ' + str(self.parameter)
```

Consider BloodParameters model has 3 parameters with type = '1'

I want to create a Django form containing these 3 parameters as input fields but the form loads up as blank. I'm trying something on these lines in my forms file :

```
class BloodReportCBCIronForm(forms.Form):
    cbc_iron_parameters = BloodParameters.objects.filter(type = 1)
    print('asd')
    print(cbc_iron_parameters.__dict__)
    for each in cbc_iron_parameters:
        each.parameter = forms.CharField(label = each.parameter,max_length = 80,required = True,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to dynamically add fields to a form, and the place to do that is inside of the form's `__init__` method. Like so:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.text import slugify


class BloodReportCBCIronForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, type, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initializes a form with a dynamic set of fields, based upon objects fetched from the database.        
        :param type: integer ID of a BloogTestType object 
        :param args: 
        :param kwargs: 
        """
        cbc_iron_parameters = BloodParameters.objects.filter(type__id=type)

        for each in cbc_iron_parameters:
            # Safety-check here, in case the each.parameter value contains spaces or symbols.
            field_name = slugify(each.parameter)
            # Add a field to the self.base_fields dictionary. Note that this doesn't deal 
            # with the scenario where there are multiple parameters with the same name.
            self.base_fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(label=each.parameter, max_length=80, required=True)

        # super() will now create fields based off of whatever you added to the self.base_fields dictionary.
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then to initialize and use the form, you'll need to do something like this:

```
form = BloodReportCBCIronForm(type=1)
```

Comment: You are awesome for teaching me this. I had dropped this idea since I couldn't get a reasonable answer for this. Will try this now and update you. Thanks again